# Quarkus Mutiny Multi and Uni memory leaks and io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked

Tags: java, multithreading, quarkus, vert.x, mutiny

I have this problem and have been stuck with it for a week now

I'm querying a huge amount of data (millions) from a DB, and then breaks them into partition using `Multi` and for each of them, process using `Uni`

My main function code looks roughly something like this:

```java
public Uni<Void>processData(Request request) {
    AtomicReference<List<Item>> listItemRef = new AtomicReference<>();
    return getAllMatchingItem(request)
            .onItem().transformToMulti(result -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(ListUtils.partition(result, 10000)))
            .onItem().transformToUni(resultBatched -> Uni.createFrom().item(() -> resultBatched)
                    .chain(resultBatched -> {
                        listItemRef.setRelease(resultBatched);
                        return getOtherItemBasedOnItem(resultBatched);
                    })
                    .chain(otherItems -> {
                        List<Item> items = listItemRef.getPlain();
                        return createProcessedItems(items, otherItems);
                    })
                    .chain(processedItems -> {
                        return insertProcessedItems(processedItems);
                    })
                    .onTermination().invoke(() -> {
                        LOGGER.info("Data process success");
                    })
                    .replaceWithVoid() // to make sure no remaining reference to upstream Unis
            )
            .merge(1)
            .collect().asList()
            .replaceWithVoid()
            .emitOn(MutinyHelper.executor(Vertx.currentContext()));
}
```

and the supporting functions are roughly like this:

```java
public Uni<List<Item>> getAllMatchingItem(Request request) {
    // get data to DB, basically PanacheRepository.find(...).list
    return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> repo.find(" ... ").list)
            .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
            .emitOn(MutinyHelper.executor(Vertx.currentContext()));
}

public Uni<List<OtherItem>> getOtherItemBasedOnItem(List<Item> items) {
    // get data to DB, basically PanacheRepository.find(id in items.getIdSet).list()
    return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> repo.find("id in ?1", items.getIDSet()).list)
            .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
            .emitOn(MutinyHelper.executor(Vertx.currentContext()));
}

public Uni<List<ProcessedItem>> createProcessedItems(List<Item> items, List<OtherItem> otherItems) {
    return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> doCreateProcessedItems(item, otherItems))
            .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
            .emitOn(MutinyHelper.executor(Vertx.currentContext()));
}

public List<ProcessedItem> doCreateProcessedItems(List<Item> items, List<OtherItem> otherItems) {
    // process those items
    // basically create Map, create list, etc
    // no external function call, just plain code
}

public Uni<Void> insertProcessedItems(List<ProcessedItem> processedItems) {
    // basically just insert/update
    return Uni.createFrom().voidItem()
            .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
            .invoke(() -> repo.persist(processedItems))
            .emitOn(MutinyHelper.executor(Vertx.currentContext()));
}
```

I suspect there are memory leaks because the log `Data process success` appears a few times before getting this exception

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I also getting this warning:

```
(vertx-blocked-thread-checker) Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 3203 ms, time limit is 2000 ms: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
2024-02-03 21:20:10,152 WARN [io.ver.cor.imp.BlockedThreadChecker] (vertx-blocked-thread-checker) Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 3203 ms, time limit is 2000 ms: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
```

I appreciate any clue I could get on how to solve this complex issue

Note: I'm using Quarkus version 2.16 if that matters

Answer (score 2):

A Vert.x thread block checker warning means that you are doing some blocking I/O and/or long-running work on an event-loop thread.

From what I see in your code I suspect that you are doing calls to Hibernate (not Reactive) and then put data from memory into reactive pipelines, eventually collecting everything as a list (`.collect().asList()`) does just that.

Reactive is great if you do it properly end-to-end with non-blocking I/O. If that's not the case I'd recommend rewriting the code as plain imperative code.

Comment: yes, I did call to hibernate in non Reactive. However I did wrap the call in reactive. It doesn't seem my team want to do it in imperative, and reactive hibernate is out of question because some blocker it has (not supporting multiple persistence unit). Can you explain more to me about what is the proper end-to-end reactive way?

Comment: if `.collect().asList()` is a bad idea. is there a better way? I don't really need the data from the finished Uni, hence I put `.replaceWithVoid()`

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue. Not with Hibernate, but with Cassandra (generated) Daos. It does not occur executing the actual business logic (querying the db) but during lazy init of the DaoBean. Running 'quarkusDev' it's working ~33% of the time, otherwise crashing the app. Tried with quarkus 3.7.4, 3.6.9.

Comment: The bean is initialized, and the app crashes when calling my Reactive REST endpoint using the bean for the first time. I'll try to initialize them eagerly as a workaround.